# Responsive square image repeating to fill window space equally

Tags: jquery, css, window, responsive-design, fill

I will try to be as clear as possible. My aim is to fill a window space equally with a fixed number of squares that would also be responsive to the windows size changes. These squares will then randomly disappear until only tree of them remain in the middle as buttons.

I have found a piece of code used for a photo gallery and tried to adapt it for my purpose, but I got stuck on the responsive part.

Here is my Index:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> SPLIT</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <script src ="jquery.sliced.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.sliced.css"/>


</head>
<body>

<div class="square"></div>

    <div id ="wrapper">
    <div id="back"></div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:-5px;
    padding-top:-10px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.tile { 
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
}


.tile:hover { 
    opacity:0; 
}
```

And my JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
;(function( $, window ) {

var _defaults = {
    x : 20, // number of tiles in x axis
    y :20, // number of tiles in y axis
    gap:2,
    random : true, // animate tiles in random order
    speed : 2000 // time to clear all tiles
};

  $.fn.splitInTiles = function( options ) {

    var o = $.extend( {}, _defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {

      var $container = $('#wrapper');
         var width = $container.width(),
          height = $container.height(),
          $back = $("#back"),
          n_tiles = o.x * o.y,
          tiles = [], $tiles;

      for ( var i = 0; i < n_tiles; i++ ) {
        tiles.push('<div class="tile"/>');
      }

      $tiles = $( tiles.join('') );

      // Hide original image and insert tiles in DOM
      $back.hide().after( $tiles );

      // Set background
      $tiles.css({
        width: width / o.x,
        height: height / o.y,
        marginBottom: o.gap +'px',
        marginRight: o.gap +'px',
      });

      // Adjust position
     $tiles.each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css( 'backgroundPosition', -pos.left +'px '+ -pos.top +'px' );
    });


    });

  };

}( jQuery, window ));

$('#back').splitInTiles();
});//]]>
```

This is the jsfiddle with the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5WyQ/13/

I can't seem to figure a way to make the squares equally fill the window space.

Comment: You realize that they will not be any more *squares* but *rectangles* once you want them to fit some size.

Comment: roXon I know what you mean but I imagined that I could also make the space between them vary so they would remain squares.

Answer (score 0):

After changing this it does work:

```
$tiles.css({
    width: Math.floor((width / o.x) + o.gap),
    height: Math.floor((height / o.y) + o.gap),
    marginBottom: o.gap + 'px',
    marginRight: o.gap + 'px'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer Christiaan, but unfortunately after the changes you suggested were made I still have an overflow of squares on the bottom and a uneven margin on the right of the window. That margin is also changing ( wider or thinner) with the window size.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a different idea, considering that I got no answer to my initial question. I think that It would also be ok if the squares would go out of the window and hide the overflow. That way maybe it would be easier to keep them square (considering the various window sizes out there). And that worked too, but unfortunately that raises two other problems: 
1. If the screen is too big (23' +) the squares seem to end abruptly not filling the whole window.
2. Depending on the screen width on certain widths I am left with a blank space (column) on the left of the screen, even if I have overflow hidden on the parent container.

I thought this would be a lot more simple and I still think that a guru would have a simple solution for filling a window with a fixed number of responsive squares, but I just can't seem to figure it out.